# Rendering elements from an array of objects cause them to flicker on the screen and disappear

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**What is the problem?**

I have a functional component that should render a list of player stats based on what team the user selects. The functionality of getting the data works and when I console log the state array using a useEffect I get an array with data inside it, but when I try to render the objects in html so you can see them on the screen sometimes they flicker on and then disappear, sometimes nothing happens at all.

**What I've tried**

I've tried using both a state array and just an ordinary variable array to see if that makes any difference. I've tried using .forEach and just a for loop to see if that would work. I've messed around with how I store the data and just trying to use a simple array instead of an object nothing so far has managed to get it rendered. As a note it is clear that the component does render as the div (className = Player-Stats) that contains the .map function is visible when inspected.

Thanks for any help and suggestions, I've spent days on this one functionality because the NHL api stores it's data super weirdly and you need to do all kinds of things to get the data you want. I didn't want to spam this question with tons of my code so if you need anything else like the parent components please ask and I can provide them.

**Code Snippets**

*Landing Page*

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import '../CSS/LandingPage.css';
import Instruction from './Instruction';
import LeagueLeaders from './LeagueLeaders';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import TeamSelector from './TeamSelector';
import TeamStandings from './TeamStandings';

function LandingPage() {

const [teamSelected, setTeamSelected] = useState(false);
const [listOfTeams, setListOfTeams] = useState([]);


  return (

    <div className = 'Landing-Page-Container'>
        <NavBar/>
        <div className = 'Stats-Standings-Container'>
          <div className = 'Team-Select-Container'>
            <TeamSelector toggleStats = {setTeamSelected} setListTeams = {setListOfTeams}/>
          </div>
            <div className = 'Stats-Container'> 
                <LeagueLeaders showStats = {teamSelected} getListTeams = {listOfTeams} />
             </div>
            <div className = 'Standings-Container'>
                <TeamStandings/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default LandingPage;
```

*LeagueLeaders code*

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import {FaChevronLeft, FaChevronRight} from 'react-icons/fa';

import '../CSS/LeagueLeaders.css';
import Instruction from './Instruction';

import LeaderStats from './LeaderStats.js';

function LeagueLeaders({showStats, getListTeams}){

    var title = ['Skaters', 'Goalies', 'Defencemen'];
    var [titleNo, setTitleNo] = useState(0);

    var goalieOptions = ['GAA', 'SV%', 'SHUTOUTS'];
    var nonGoalieOptions = ['POINTS', 'GOALS', 'ASSISTS'];


    function selectPosition(task){
        if(task === '+' && titleNo <2){
            setTitleNo(titleNo+1);
        }else if (task === '+' && titleNo == 2){
            setTitleNo(0);
        }else if(task === '-' && titleNo >0){
            setTitleNo(titleNo-1);
        }else{
            setTitleNo(2);
        }

        
    }


    return(
        <div className = 'Leaders-Container'>
            <div className = 'Leaders-Title'>
                
                   <FaChevronLeft className = 'toggleArrow' size = {24} color = 'white' onClick={() => selectPosition('-')}/> 
              
                
                <h1>{title[titleNo]}</h1>
                
                   <FaChevronRight className = 'toggleArrow' size = {24} color = 'white' onClick={() => selectPosition('+')}/> 
                
                
            </div>
            <div className = 'Leaders-Selection-Container'>
                <div className = 'Stat-Select-1'>
                    <p>{titleNo == 1 ? goalieOptions[0]: nonGoalieOptions[0]}</p>
                </div>
                <div className = 'Stat-Select-2'>
                    <p>{titleNo == 1 ? goalieOptions[1]: nonGoalieOptions[1]}</p>
                </div>
                <div className = 'Stat-Select-3'>
                    <p>{titleNo == 1 ? goalieOptions[2]: nonGoalieOptions[2]}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className = 'Leaders-Stats-Container'>
                {showStats ? <LeaderStats playerPos = {titleNo} teams = {getListTeams}/> : <Instruction/>}
            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default LeagueLeaders;
```

*TeamSelector component code*

```
import '../CSS/TeamSelector.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import teamDetail from "../Assets/teamDetail";

function TeamSelector( {toggleStats, setListTeams}) {

    const [listOfTeams, setListOfTeams] = useState([]);
    const [listOfURL, setListOfURL] = useState([]);
    const [selectedTeams, setSelectedTeams] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(selectedTeams);
        setListTeams(selectedTeams);
        
    }, [selectedTeams])
    

    function handleClick(e){

        const selectedTeamsCopy = [...selectedTeams];
        if(selectedTeams.includes(e.currentTarget.id)){
            if(selectedTeams.length <= 1){
                toggleStats(false);
                selectedTeamsCopy.splice(selectedTeamsCopy.indexOf(e.currentTarget.id, 1), 1);
                setSelectedTeams(selectedTeamsCopy);
            }else{
                selectedTeamsCopy.splice(selectedTeamsCopy.indexOf(e.currentTarget.id, 1), 1);
                setSelectedTeams(selectedTeamsCopy);
            }
        }else {
            if(selectedTeams.length === 0){
                toggleStats(true);
                selectedTeamsCopy.push(e.currentTarget.id);
                setSelectedTeams(selectedTeamsCopy);
            }else{
                selectedTeamsCopy.push(e.currentTarget.id);
                setSelectedTeams(selectedTeamsCopy);
            }
        }

        if(e.target.style.opacity === '1'){
            e.target.style.opacity = '25%';
        }else {
            e.target.style.opacity = '100%';
        }
        
    }

return (
     
        <div className = 'Team-Logo-Container'>
            {teamDetail.map((Teams)=>(
                
                <div>
                    <img onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)} key = {Teams.ID} id = {Teams.ID} alt = {Teams.Name +' Logo'} src = {Teams.URL} className = 'logo'/>
                </div>
            ))}


        </div>
    
    
    );
  }
  
  export default TeamSelector;
```

*Array of objects layout*

```
[{ ID: "8480003", Name: "Jesper Boqvist", Points: "1", … }, { ID: "8475193", Name: "Tomas Tatar", Points: "10", … }, etc. etc.]
```

*Rendering the array*

```
return(

  <div className = 'Player-Stats'>
      {triggerStats ? listOfStats.map((d)=>{
        return <p className = 'Stats' key={d.ID}>{d.ID}</p>}
      ) : <p className = 'Stats'> Sorry theres no available data</p>}            
  </div>
    )
```

*LeaderStats component script (Where the rendering issue is)*

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import '../CSS/LeaderStats.css';

function LeaderStats({playerPos, teams}){
const isInitialMount = useRef(true);

const [listOfStats, setListOfStats] = useState([]);

const [triggerStats, setTriggerStats] = useState(false);

//If it's not the first render and the listOfStats state has changed it will render the stats of the players
useEffect(()=>{
  if(!isInitialMount.current){
    console.log(listOfStats);
   
    setTriggerStats(true);
  }
  
}, [listOfStats])

//When teams prop changes, run the function to get player data from API
useEffect(()=>{

  if (isInitialMount.current) {
    isInitialMount.current = false;
 }else{
  if(teams.length !== 0){
   
    getPlayerIDs(teams);
  }else{
    
    setTriggerStats(false);
  }
}
},[teams])

//This function runs all the axios calls and gathers data from multiple endpoints and saves it to an array     
function getPlayerIDs(teamID){

  const axios = require('axios');
  var playerList=[];
  var tempObj;

  teamID.forEach(d => 
    
    axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/${parseInt(d)}/roster`).then(res => {
    
    //If user has selected the forward position filter roster by that player position and get the stats and save to temp array.
    if(playerPos === 0){
      res.data.roster.filter(obj => obj.position.type === 'Forward').map(e=> 
        axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${e.person.id}/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20212022`).then(res =>{
          if(typeof res.data.stats[0].splits[0] !== 'undefined'){
            if(playerPos !== 1 ){
              tempObj = { ID: `${e.person.id}`, Name: `${e.person.fullName}` ,Points: `${res.data.stats[0].splits[0].stat.points}`, Goals: `${res.data.stats[0].splits[0].stat.goals}`, Assists: `${res.data.stats[0].splits[0].stat.assists}`};
              playerList.push(tempObj);
            }
          }

        })
      );

    }
    //If user has selected the goalie position filter roster by that player position and get the stats and save to temp array.

    else if(playerPos === 1){
      res.data.roster.filter(obj => obj.position.type === 'Goalie').map(e=> 
        axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${e.person.id}/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20212022`).then(res =>{
          if(typeof res.data.stats[0].splits[0] !== 'undefined'){
            if(playerPos !== 1 ){
              tempObj = { ID: `${e.person.id}`, Name: `${e.person.fullName}`, GAA: `${res.data.stats[0].splits[0].stat.goalAgainstAverage}`, SavePercentage: `${res.data.stats[0].splits[0].stat.savePercentage}`, Shutouts: `${res.data.stats[0].splits[0].stat.shutouts}`};
              playerList.push(tempObj);
            }
          }

        })
      );
    }
    //If user has selected the defense position filter roster by that player position and get the stats and save to temp array.

    else if(playerPos === 2){
      res.data.roster.filter(obj => obj.position.type === 'Defenseman').map(e=> 
        axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${e.person.id}/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20212022`).then(res =>{
          if(typeof res.data.stats[0].splits[0] !== 'undefined'){
            if(playerPos !== 1 ){
              tempObj = { ID: `${e.person.id}`, Name: `${e.person.fullName}` ,Points: `${res.data.stats[0].splits[0].stat.points}`, Goals: `${res.data.stats[0].splits[0].stat.goals}`, Assists: `${res.data.stats[0].splits[0].stat.assists}`};
              playerList.push(tempObj);
            }
          }

        })
      );
    }
    
    })
  );
  //Set the state to the temp array that will be used to render the stats
  setListOfStats(playerList);
}




  return(

  <div className = 'Player-Stats'>
      {triggerStats ? listOfStats.map((d)=>{
        return <p className = 'Stats' key={d.ID}>{d.ID}</p>}
      ) : <p className = 'Stats'> Sorry theres no available data</p>}            
  </div>
    )
  
  
}
export default LeaderStats;
```

Comment: How do you pass `teams` to the component? Can you share the code?

Comment: I posted the code that generates the teams list. So the Landing page stores the main definition of teams (the actual useState), the team selector component gets the setter passed to it and has the selected teams added to that state in the first useEffect (after the handleclick has ran). The leagueLeaders component gets the getter of the state and directly passes that without change to the leaderStats component which is acessed as teams in the component where the render is supposed to happen.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to figure out the issue so I'll post it here for those of you who in the future might find yourself in the same position as me without being able to find an answer. Turns out the way I was setting `setListOfStats(playerList);` made the state change without me realising it and by the time it got to rendering the .map there was nothing actually there as console.log takes a snapshot of the state at the time of the console.log. The solution (which I had experimented with before a few times but couldn't get working) was to remove the temprorary array of playerList completely and change the following code `playerList.push(tempObj);` to `setListOfStats(listOfStats => [...listOfStats, tempObj])` thise line of code essentially sets the list of stats as I did before but it captures the previous state as well. This comes up with another issue of when you want to remove some data from the list but that's not related to this question. Hopefully someone can make use of this answer in the future.